# How do I pass parameter to the form in Django?

Tags: django

So as the title states, I'm trying to pass a parameter from views to forms. I've seen several Stack Overflow posts regarding this issue, but none of them solved my problem :( 
So what I'm trying to build is basically a question-and-answer application. Each user answers to pre-provided questions.  I want to make an answering template for each corresponding question. 
 So here's my code:

 forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    main_answer = formsCharField(required=True)
    # Some other fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.q = kwargs.pop('q')
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['main_answer'].label = q.main_question
```

views.py

```
def createAnswer(request, pk):
    thisQuestion = Question.objects.get(question_number=pk)
    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerForm(q = thisQuestion), extra=1)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(queryset=Answer.objects.filter(authuser=request.user.id, question_number=pk))
    
    # And some other codes
```

I'm supposed to show this formset in my template using `{% crispy_formset%}`. However I keep getting this error: "name 'q' is not defined". What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass these when you *construct* the `FormSet` with the [**`form_kwargs=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms):

```
def createAnswer(request, pk):
    thisQuestion = Question.objects.get(question_number=pk)
    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Aswer, form=AnswerForm, extra=1)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(
        form_kwargs={'q': thisQuestion},
        queryset=Answer.objects.filter(authuser=request.user.id, question_number=pk)
    )
```

You also will get a name error, because you use `q` in the `__init__` method, but `q` is not defined:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    main_answer = formsCharField(required=True)
    # Some other fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ↓ assign to a local variable q
        q = self.q = kwargs.pop('q')
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['main_answer'].label = q.main_question
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I did exactly as you explained, and changed ```modelformset_factory(...)``` to ```formset_factory(...)``` and got this error : ```formset_factory() got multiple values for argument 'form'```. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: @RyanOh: you should remove the `Answer` from as first parameter.

Comment: Thanks! But now I get this ```: _init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'``` :(

Comment: @RyanOh: sorry, I misunderstood it, then you probably indeed need a `modelformset` :s (sorry).

Comment: No worries. Now I've changed it into ```modelformset_factory```, and now I get "name 'q' is not defined" error in my forms.py. What's wrong now? I'm sorry for the frequent errors :(

Comment: @RyanOh: this is because you did not assign `q` to a local variable, see edit.